# HTTP Client Request with headers and POST in DotNet?

Tags: c#

in Java I have a HTTPClient which use Headers in a POST Method with a website to send a request and get a answer.

With which component I can do that in C#.net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about [`HttpWebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

If you mean, "what is the equivalent way of writing a simple http client in C#?", then you have a few options.

The most obvious is the `System.Net.WebClient`class. This is a nice and simple, easy to use, web client that provides functionality for the most common web operations.

If you wanted to go a little deeper, then the `System.Net.HttpWebRequest` and `System.Net.HttpWebResponse` classes give you access to lower level workings of http web requests and responses.